# SQL, creating a new table with auto generated passords from other tables

Tags: sql-server, select, table

i have this sql below which i have retrieved from our student database. It retreives all that i need, but i would like to create a new table which includes all the tables plus one column with auto generated passwords.

Is this possible?

```
SELECT
    CurrentPupil.SchoolID AS 'SchoolID',
    CurrentPupil.PupilID AS 'PupilID',
    PupilPersonalDetails.Surname AS 'Surname',
    PupilPersonalDetails.Forename AS 'First_Name',
    PupilPersonalDetailsGenderLookupDetails.Description AS 'Gender',
    ContactMaster.LastName AS 'Contact_Last_Name',
    ContactMaster.FirstName AS 'Contact_First_Name',
    ContactMasterGenderLookupDetails.Description AS 'Contact_Gender',
    ContactMaster.LastName2 AS 'Contact_Last_Name_2',
    ContactMaster.FirstName2 AS 'Contact_First_Name_2',
    ContactMasterGender2LookupDetails.Description AS 'Contact_Gender_2',
    ContactEmailInformation.EmailID AS 'Contact_Email_Address',
    PupilCurrentSchoolYearGroupLookupDetails.Description AS 'Year_Group',
    PupilCurrentSchoolFormSchoolLookupDetails.Description AS 'Form',
    ContactMaster.ContactID
FROM
    win2k12engage.EngageSpratton.dbo.CurrentPupil
LEFT OUTER JOIN win2k12engage.EngageSpratton.dbo.PupilPersonalDetails AS PupilPersonalDetails ON CurrentPupil.SchoolID = PupilPersonalDetails.SchoolID
AND CurrentPupil.PupilID = PupilPersonalDetails.PupilID
LEFT OUTER JOIN win2k12engage.EngageSpratton.dbo.LookupDetails AS PupilPersonalDetailsGenderLookupDetails ON PupilPersonalDetailsGenderLookupDetails.LookupDetailsID = PupilPersonalDetails.Gender
AND PupilPersonalDetailsGenderLookupDetails.LookupID = '20003'
LEFT OUTER JOIN win2k12engage.EngageSpratton.dbo.PupilContacts AS PupilContacts ON CurrentPupil.SchoolID = PupilContacts.SchoolID
AND CurrentPupil.PupilID = PupilContacts.PupilID
LEFT OUTER JOIN win2k12engage.EngageSpratton.dbo.ContactMaster AS ContactMaster ON PupilContacts.ContactID = ContactMaster.ContactID
LEFT OUTER JOIN win2k12engage.EngageSpratton.dbo.ContactEmailInformation AS ContactEmailInformation ON ContactMaster.ContactID = ContactEmailInformation.ContactID
LEFT OUTER JOIN win2k12engage.EngageSpratton.dbo.LookupDetails AS ContactMasterGenderLookupDetails ON ContactMasterGenderLookupDetails.LookupDetailsID = ContactMaster.Gender
AND ContactMasterGenderLookupDetails.LookupID = '20003'
LEFT OUTER JOIN win2k12engage.EngageSpratton.dbo.LookupDetails AS ContactMasterGender2LookupDetails ON ContactMasterGender2LookupDetails.LookupDetailsID = ContactMaster.Gender2
AND ContactMasterGender2LookupDetails.LookupID = '20003'
LEFT OUTER JOIN win2k12engage.EngageSpratton.dbo.PupilCurrentSchool AS PupilCurrentSchool ON CurrentPupil.SchoolID = PupilCurrentSchool.SchoolID
AND CurrentPupil.PupilID = PupilCurrentSchool.PupilID
LEFT OUTER JOIN win2k12engage.EngageSpratton.dbo.LookupDetails AS PupilCurrentSchoolYearGroupLookupDetails ON PupilCurrentSchoolYearGroupLookupDetails.LookupDetailsID = PupilCurrentSchool.YearGroup
AND PupilCurrentSchoolYearGroupLookupDetails.LookupID = '3004'
LEFT OUTER JOIN win2k12engage.EngageSpratton.dbo.SchoolLookupDetails AS PupilCurrentSchoolFormSchoolLookupDetails ON PupilCurrentSchoolFormSchoolLookupDetails.LookupDetailsID = PupilCurrentSchool.Form
AND PupilCurrentSchoolFormSchoolLookupDetails.LookupID = '1002'
WHERE
    ('%wc%' = '%wc%')
```

*************************************UPDATE***************************
Hi Guys back to my desk. I am adding one additional column to the current query and have that additional column contain a random string of data that would be a password...also
the tables / columns above are from a database that i cannot write to but only read, so i use the win2k12engage.EngageSpratton.dbo.fieldname to connect to my other database Eletter.dbo.newtable where i want to have all the fields above plus one more column with the password.

Cheers

Many thanks in advance
Vitor

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  Are you simply wanting to add one additional column to your current query and have that additional column contain a random string of data that would be a `password`?  It would be very helpful if you'd update your question to include sample data and expected results.

Comment: How random does it have to be? Could you use something like this? `SELECT REPLACE(NEWID(), '-', '') AS pw
FROM sys.all_objects AS ao;`

Comment: HI Scott, thank you so much for the quick response. basically about these tables i can not write to them, i can only create tables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Database to test this on, but Potentially, you could use DEFAULT, RAND() and REPLACE() to do this.

`CREATE TABLE Users(
     ID int NOT NULL,
     LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     FirstName varchar(255),
     Password varchar(255) DEFAULT REPLACE(FLOOR(RAND()*(987654321-123456789+1))+123456789,'1','!')
 );`

Just keep adding more REPLACE to make the Password a bit more Complex with each.